# Why isn't it filling in when I extrude?

Tags: mesh, extrude

I have a mesh plane, but it won't extrude correctly. I started Blender today, so I am completely new. Here are the pictures:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKbq6.png)

[image]

Comment: you mean you've extruded but there are no rim?

Comment: rim? If that is the fill that is supposed to fill the gap between the two planes then yes.

Comment: yes, no side... have you used E to extrude? It looks like you've made a simple duplication

Comment: Yes I use E to extrude

Comment: I can't tell you what's happening but I can confirm that it's not the way it's supposed to work  :/

Comment: Dangit. Well, thanks anyway.

Comment: If you selected the whole mesh and extruded it, it is the expected result. To get what you want just select the outer edges of the mesh and extrude it upwards then if you wanna close the top just extrude it aing and press s to scale the extrusion inwards and then press alt+m(assuming it is a circle with a triangle fan filling)

Comment: Could you upload your blender file so that we can try to figure out what's causing this to happen: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/  Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't appear like a circle.. is it a subdivided plane?If so I'd recommend to delete all the subdivisions and then extrude it . Afterwards you can add loopcuts.

Comment: Thank you Nxdhin2005 it worked! But it's very tedious to select the outer edge, is there a short cut of doing that process?

Comment: Hold down Alt when selecting an edge - it will select all "connected" edges.

Comment: Thank you, Christopher!

Answer (score 1):

Tricks to get this to work:

1. Apply *object scale* then extrude.
2. Select vertices/edges around the edge of the plane/circle and extrude.
3. Change the edit mode select mode to "edges" instead of faces or vertices and select the edges then extrude.

Hope these tips answer your question.